# Ffmpeg command to mux in subtitles matching the style of VLC

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles

I am trying to mux in subtitles with ffmpeg, but I am having trouble getting the desired style and output with a reference point being VLC's standard format of showing subtitles matching the look of the subtitles below (when selecting standard.srt files in VLC):

[VLC standard subtitle format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytuMX.png)

What would be the command to achieve this exact output style for burning subtitles into a video file? I have tried commands looking like this one, but to no avail so far in getting it to match the VLC standard subtitle style:

`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vf "subtitles=sub.srt:force_style='FontName=Arial,FontSize=22,PrimaryColour=&Hffffff&,SecondaryColour=&Hffffff&,OutlineColour=&H000000&,BorderStyle=3,Shadow=1,Outline=2" output.mkv`

I have been trying to extract a style from the VLC settings by tweaking some of the parameters, but no matter what I try to adjust it seems to give an undesired output style or format

Comment: I think, you didn't close the quotes: `...,Outline=2' " ...`

Comment: @БаярГончикжапов I got it working and tweaked some of the settings, but I find it hard to impossible to imitate the style of VLC. If someone has some good styling commands or one which achieves the desired VLC look I would be more than happy if someone would share them here

Comment: try `FontName=Arial,FontSize=22,PrimaryColour=&H00ffffff,OutlineColour=&H00000000,BackColour=&H7f000000,BorderStyle=1,Shadow=1,Outline=1`

Comment: @БаярГончикжапов The output is looking great and just what I was looking for - thanks for the help!